# Spreadsheetの履歴をエクスポート

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Spreadsheetの変更履歴が多すぎるため、表示に時間がかかることから一度変更履歴をエクスポートしたいと考えています。
標準で履歴のエクスポート機能はないですが、スクリプトで抽出できる方法があるのではないかと思い質問させて頂きます。もしどなたかご存知でしたら教えてください。

Comment: 仮にエクスポートが出来ても元のシートには履歴が残った状態になりそうですが、やりたいことは本当にエクスポートであっていますか？(いったんエクスポートしてから削除するつもり、ですかね？)

Comment: いえ、削除する予定はなく、単純に履歴をエクスポートしたいだけです。よろしくお願いします。